# Sencha Touch - Create New Model/View/Controller from JSON

Tags: ajax, json, model-view-controller, sencha-touch

I'm rather new to Sencha Touch and currently considering it for a new project. I have spent a couple days searching the internet and watched have watched a dozen videos already, everything that Sencha presents is very promising, however I have not been able to find in any information that help me with a specific problem.

The app that is being developed requires it to be build and published in stages.  The initial deadline is very short and requires the app to morph from one form to another as the stages change. This means the menus, pages, structures etc. will call change. I am looking to use ajax(or something similar) to dynamically manipulate the content (including layout and structure) in the app.  For this reason I need to know if it is possible to pass JSON or a text string (maybe .js) with information to construct new model/controller/view to Sencha Touch app and use it dynamically in the app?

It seems that it could be either trivial or complex, but as I am new to Sencha Touch I would like to hear from someone with experience before I put all my eggs in one basket.  Can anyone help point me in the right direction? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The app you build using Sencha Touch would reside on your web server. Clients (browser or mobile devices) would download copy of your application and will run them locally.

When you release new version of the app - you will update your web server with the new code. When client would run it again it will automatically check if the server version is newer and will update their local copy accordingly. Sencha provides this logic out-of-the-box. User will see a message that application has been updated and it will refresh automatically.

The only other scenario is not covered by this logic - user has application running and you're updating server at the same time. For this I think you would need to implement some code to deal with it. But it will not be "load new menus via Ajax calls", it would be something similar to built-in logic "check the server, if there is new version - refresh".

Hope that answers your question.